# What is the best practice to share general/common types across the entire project? (react + typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Consider this component

```
type CardProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: React.ReactNode;
};

const Card: FC<CardProps> = ({ children, className }: CardProps) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

**The problem**

- I don't want to define a type to require `children` for every component that needs it.
- For the most part, almost all my components are divs with an optional `className` prop.

**Solution**

The solution I see is to define common props that are reusable across the project

```
export type WithChildren = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: React.ReactNode;
};
```

that will allow me to write the component above like this

```
import { WithChildren } from '~/where?/that/is/the/question';

type Props = WithChildren & {
  custom: string[];
};

const Card: FC<Props> = ({ children, className }: Props) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

or maybe

```
import { WithChildren } from '~/where?/that/is/the/question';

type Props = {
  custom: string[];
} & WithChildren;

const Card: FC<Props> = ({ children, className, custom }: Props) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {children}
    <div>{custom.length}</div>
  </div>
);
```

**The question**

What is the good practice to share that kind of types across the entire project?

So far I've search for projects but all they do is write `declare` and `namespace` in a `global.d.ts` file at the root of the project, but, still I'm not sure if I'm doing some kind of bad pattern, or if there is already a good pattern defined for that kind of situations.

Currently I'm thinking on writing something like this

```
// global.d.ts
export type WithChildren = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: React.ReactNode;
};
```

All suggestions are welcome.

## EDIT: Aug/05/2020

There is a type constructor `React.PropsWithChildren` that will require the children prop

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import { WithClassName } from '~/where?/that/is/the/question';

type CustomProps = {
  custom: string[];
} & WithClassName;

type Props = PropsWithChildren<CustomProps>;

const Card: FC<Props> = ({ children, className, custom }: Props) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {children}
    <div>{custom.length}</div>
  </div>
);
```

But, the question about re-using generic types is still on.

Answer (score -1):

`children` is already defined for all Function components. So the correct code is:

```
type CardProps = {
  // children: React.ReactNode; No need!
  className?: React.ReactNode;
};

// Will still work! 
const Card: FC<CardProps> = ({ children, className }: CardProps) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: that's not true, typescript will complain if I don't write a type for the children prop.